# "Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)"

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, fedora

After fully reinstalling Fedora to version 36, I got this error:

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
>
> '/sbin/vboxconfig'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On Linux, open returned ENOENT

Commands from other topics that don't work:

```
sudo dnf reinstall kernel-devel kernel-headers dkms qt5-qtx11extras  elfutils-libelf-devel zlib-devel
systemctl restart vboxdrv
sudo dnf reinstall VirtualBox-6.1
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try:

```
$ sudo dnf -y install @development-tools
$ sudo dnf install kernel-headers kernel-devel dkms  -y
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe it is that the kernels have different versions on devel and headers. You should probably check this right before everything else.

Now if you want to create a virtual machine based on Linux, I strongly recommend you to use "KVM", it's the easiest way and it should work without any trouble.

This is related: [rc-1908](https://superuser.com/questions/1582139/kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908-on-fedora-32)

Answer (score -1):

You just need to install the `linux-devel` packages (it worked in fedora 37):

```
sudo dnf install linux-devel
```